# difference: "namely" and "e.g."

Tags: appositives

Would there be any difference if "namely" were replaced by "e.g." in the following? Some say "namely" means "that is (to say)" or "i.e." and is used to explain a more general term. But in the following sentence, "namely" is used rather like "e.g."

> The disease can be prevented, namely, by exercising, eating right, and not
> smoking.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

"E.g." is actually a Latin abbreviation for *exempli gratia*, meaning "for example". It implies that whatever comes after it is just one or more examples of the subject that came before it. It is not an exhaustive list.

Consider this sentence:

> My dog enjoys playing with squishy toys, *e.g.*, balls and rubber ducks.

In this case, I'm giving examples of "squishy toys", but clearly balls and rubber ducks are not the only squishy toys in existence.

Contrast this to the Latin expression *i.e.*, meaning *id est*, or literally "that is". This implies that whatever follows is actually the description of what you said before, and there is nothing more to consider.

> We only accept cash, *i.e.*, United States dollar bills.

This is elaborating on what is meant by "cash" and is expressing that the shop literally only accepts US paper currency. It's not an example; they don't accept Euros.

How does this relate to "namely"? "Namely" is effectively a synonym for "*i.e.*" (as is the Latin abbreviation *viz.* and the phrase "to wit", if you've ever seen those). It means that whatever follows is explaining or describing what came before, not giving an example of what came before.

You should only use "namely" (or *i.e.*, *viz.* or "to wit") if you intend to limit whatever follows the expression to exhaustively describe your subject. If you intend to give examples only and not an exhaustive list, you should use *e.g.* or, better (since not everyone understands the Latin phrases), "for example".

(Edit to add:)

In the example you gave:

> The disease can be prevented, namely, by exercising, eating right, and not smoking.

The sentence is trying to say that the disease can be prevented by exercising, eating right, and not smoking. That's it — it can't be prevented by doing anything else.

Despite my explanation above, you will occasionally seen these rules misused. One way to catch on to that is if the list ends with "etc." or "and so on" or some other phrase that tries to indicate there are other items other than what is listed. So if you see something like this:

> I like dark colored cars, namely, black, blue, etc.

... what that person actually meant was "for example" and not "namely".

Comment: In your examples, "i.e." or "namely" comes after a general expression that is to be elaborated on, such as "dark-colored cars" and "cash."  But there is no such general expression in my example.

Comment: I agree. The sentence should read "The disease can be prevented in three ways, namely..."

Comment: @KateBunting: I disagree that those are three discrete ways to prevent said disease. The use of the word "and" in the list implies that all three are required. The use of "namely" is intended to elaborate on how the disease can be prevented. Traditionally "namely" is used for an exhaustive list. That said, I can't tell whether the author in this case used it appropriately.

Comment: @Apollyon: My examples do give general expressions, true, but it's not the only time you can use "namely". In fact, the [definition of the word](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/namely?s=t) is "that is to say; explicitly; specifically; to wit". It suggests that whatever comes after the word is elaborating, and specifically describing, whatever came before it. In this case, the way the disease can be prevented.

Comment: Is it natural to say "The disease can be prevented, that is, by exercising, eating right, and not smoking"?

Comment: Could it be that my original sentence does refer to a general expression, but in a previous sentence?

Comment: I still think that expressions such as _namely, e.g., that is._ need to refer to a noun. If RawrRenn disputes that the three items in the list can be considered separately, then I would suggest "There is a way of preventing the disease, that is/namely by exercising, eating right and not smoking."